# XML LINQ statement almost giving desired results

Tags: xml, linq

I have a situation that needs some other eyes. I have two different XML files that I am joing through a LINQ statement to give specific values in a specific order and for the most part I have it working correctly. What I am missing is the order of just one of these pieces so I hope someone can help here.

The first file I call the Template:

```
<CARENetIn>
<transaction>
    <TimeStamp value="Fri Jan 03 07:57:39 CDT 2014" />
    <RequestCode value="ResetPassword" />
    <RetryCount value="0" />
    <ApplicationName value="CARE GENMED CLIENT" />
    <PlaylistName value="ResetPassword" />
</transaction>
<payload>
    <payloadItem name="LogonUserId">
        <value>CARE</value>
    </payloadItem>
    <payloadItem name="LogonPassword">
        <value>admin</value>
    </payloadItem>
    <payloadItem name="UserId">
        <value>HJones</value>
    </payloadItem>
    <payloadItem name="Password">
        <value>pass@word!</value>
    </payloadItem>
    <repeatedDataList>
        <repeatedItem>
            <payloadItem name="Test Key 1">
                <value>Test 1</value>
            </payloadItem>
            <payloadItem name="Test Key 2">
                <value>Test 2</value>
            </payloadItem>
        </repeatedItem>
        <repeatedItem>
            <payloadItem name="Test Key 1">
                <value>Test 3</value>
            </payloadItem>
            <payloadItem name="Test Key 2">
                <value>Test 4</value>
            </payloadItem>
        </repeatedItem>
    </repeatedDataList>
</payload>
</CARENetIn>
```

The second file I call the Playlist (with certain parts deleted for confidentiality, length and clarity):

```
<CARENet>
<CARENetID>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
</CARENetID>
<action type="SetText">
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    <fieldName>LogonUserId</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="SetText">
    <sequence>2</sequence>
    <fieldName>LogonPassword</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="PressButton">
    <sequence>3</sequence>
    <fieldName>Logon</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="TabSelect">
    <sequence>4</sequence>
    <fieldName>Modify</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="SetListBoxItem">
    <sequence>5</sequence>
    <fieldName>UserId</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="PressButton">
    <sequence>6</sequence>
    <fieldName>LoadUser</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="SetText">
    <sequence>7</sequence>
    <fieldName>Password</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="PressButton">
    <sequence>8</sequence>
    <fieldName>Update</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="SetText">
    <sequence>9</sequence>
    <fieldName>Test Key 1</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="SetListBoxItem">
    <sequence>10</sequence>
    <fieldName>GroupID</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="SetText">
    <sequence>11</sequence>
    <fieldName>Test Key 2</fieldName>
</action>
<action type="PressButton">
    <sequence>12</sequence>
    <fieldName>Exit</fieldName>
</action>
</CARENet>
```

Now, I have a LINQ statement joining these two lists that should essentially get all the values and REPEAT the repeated data list tags WITH the action tag between the two. Here is the statement:

```
XDocument template = XDocument.Load(@"C:\CARE\Playlists\XML Repeated Test.xml");
XDocument playlist = XDocument.Load(@"C:\CARE\Playlists\RepeatedPlaylist.xml");

var action = from actionList in playlist.Descendants(XMLPlaylistAction.Root)
             join payloadList in template.Descendants(XMLIn.PayloadItem)
             on actionList.Descendants(XMLPlaylistAction.FieldName).First().Value.ToLower() equals
             payloadList.Attributes().First().Value.ToLower()
             into joined
             from subList in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 ID = (subList == null ? string.Empty : subList.Attributes().First().Value.ToString()),

                 Value = (subList == null ? string.Empty : subList.Elements().First().Value.ToString()),

                 Action = actionList.Attributes().First().Value.ToString()
             };
```

Now, the results of this as I loop through them get me ALL the pieces I need and for the most part in the correct order. The statement USED to say FirstOrDefault instead of First and that got the repeated values in order at least, but there is a step to be seen between the two values and it shows up AFTER the repeated values. It needs to happen each time in the repeated data values.

How can I adjust the LINQ statement to show the step between the repeated values?

So, just to clarify, the results see this:

```
LogonUserID - SetText
LogonPassword - SetText
PressButton
TabSelect
UserId - SetListBoxItem
PressButton
Password - SetText
PressButton
TestKey1 - SetText
TestKey2 - SetText
TestKey1 - SetText
TestKey2 - SetText
SetListBoxItem
PressButton
```

What I WANT to see is this:

```
LogonUserID - SetText
LogonPassword - SetText
PressButton
TabSelect
UserId - SetListBoxItem
PressButton
Password - SetText
PressButton
TestKey1 - SetText
SetListBoxItem
TestKey2 - SetText
TestKey1 - SetText
SetListBoxItem
TestKey2 - SetText
PressButton
```

I would appreciate any and all ideas here. Thanks guys!

Comment: Ok. I added something to the query and now the four pieces in question (the data needed to repeat) have unique sequence numbers allotted only for those bits. How can I order JUST those 4 pieces into ascending order? I went back and verified my initial results and the test keys are not in order as you see them above, they go all 1s first, then the 2s. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about my idea, although it is not the best way.

I use `struct MyResult` instead of anonymous types.

```
public struct MyResult
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (ID != null) ? string.Format("{0} - {1}", ID, Action) : Action;
    }
}
```

Here is the code to get the result you want.

```
XDocument template = XDocument.Load(@"C:\CARE\Playlists\XML Repeated Test.xml");
XDocument playlist = XDocument.Load(@"C:\CARE\Playlists\RepeatedPlaylist.xml");

var listSrc = (from payloadList in template.Descendants("payloadItem")
            join actionList in playlist.Descendants("action")
            on payloadList.Attributes().First().Value.ToLower() equals
            actionList.Descendants("fieldName").First().Value.ToLower()
            select new MyResult
            {
                Sequence = int.Parse(actionList.Elements("sequence").First().Value),
                ID = payloadList.Attributes().First().Value,
                Value = payloadList.Elements().First().Value,
                Action = actionList.Attributes().First().Value
            }).ToList();

List<MyResult> listDst = new List<MyResult>();

listDst.Add(listSrc.First());

for (int i = 0; i < listSrc.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    if (listSrc[i].Sequence < listSrc[i + 1].Sequence)
    {
        for (int j = listSrc[i].Sequence + 1; j < listSrc[i + 1].Sequence; j++)
        {
            listDst.Add(new MyResult
            {
                Action = playlist.Descendants("action")
                .First(_ => _.Elements("sequence").First().Value == j.ToString())
                .Attributes().First().Value
            });
        }
    }
    listDst.Add(listSrc[i + 1]);
}
for (int i = listSrc.Last().Sequence; i <= int.Parse(playlist.Descendants("action").Elements("sequence").Last().Value); i++)
{
    listDst.Add(new MyResult
    {
        Action = playlist.Descendants("action")
        .First(_ => _.Elements("sequence").First().Value == i.ToString())
        .Attributes().First().Value
    });
}

foreach (var item in listDst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Ok ... that worked. It put the desired actions in the correct order. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I want to thank you for the time you put into the answer here. This was a difficult situation to encounter and my LINQ experience is not that great. This solution does work very well, although I will have to tweak it a little bit for some other pieces of this puzzle. These were just the primary bits I needed. Excellent work and very much appreciated!

Comment: However, one thing. Yes, the desired sub actions did come in order, the piece between the two (setting the text) did not get repeated. I wonder if I use another index in the Action list to identify the repeated steps that may work....

Comment: Ok ... my apologies. The results DID happen the correct way save for one bit. The sequence number 15 (the third element of the second repeated data section) gets inserted into the list one time more than it should be. So, somewhere in the loops adding the elements to the lists, there is a condition that allows for just ONE more element to be added. And it's only in the second set of repeated data. I am not sure if that is significant, but it is a DRAMATIC improvement over what I Was attempting to do. Thank you again for your efforts here!

Comment: Found it. In the second loop, add one to the initialization of the integer "i". `for (int i = listSrc.Last().Sequence + 1;`